# How to make local .json file accessible from remote machine or folder?

Tags: javascript, node-modules

In my program I have .json file that is stored in my local folder. I also have Javascript code in the same folder that accessing this .json file and reads it's values. To access the file I am using:

`const data = require('../JS/countries.json');`.

The program works perfectly on my local machine, and I have published it on github repository(https://github.com/TheRadioDept/technical-question). However, after I tried cloning this repository into another folder, I faced an error:

```
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [ '/home/me/progs/clonedRepo/technical-question/main.js' ]
```

`[ '/home/me/progs/clonedRepo/technical-question/main.js' ]` is the path to cloned repository, it is not original storage of .json file and javascript code.
That means that code can only be executed on my local machine from the original folder where I store my JS and JSON files. Is there a way I can run this code and access it in another folder or computer?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. You should add the JSON file to your Git repository.

Comment: @jabaa JSON file is added into repository. But if you clone repository and try to run Javascript code on your local machine it won't work. You can try yourself https://github.com/TheRadioDept/technical-question

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow have to be self-contained. All necessary details have to be in the question. External links can break and the question becomes useless. The path to the JSON file is wrong.

Comment: @jabaa Okay. I have edited the question to make it clear. Do you know the solution for the problem?

Comment: Yes, the path is wrong. `main.js` and the JSON file are in the same folder. There is no reason to traverse upwards and into a non-existent folder

Comment: But this question isn't answerable because of missing details in the question.

Comment: @jabaa That does not solves the problem. I am still unable to run the program even if I change the path. Were you able running it?

Comment: @jabaa what details do you need? I shared with you github link, you can clone repo and see the problem yourself....

Comment: All necessary details have to be in the question, not in an external link. You're asking for help. You should follow the rules and not force your own rules. But I already answered your question. The path is wrong.

Comment: @jabaa If I fix the path, I will be able to run this code on remote machine? And if yes, can you tell me how to fix it please?

Comment: Can you fix your question first? I can write an answer.

Comment: @jabaa it is fixed. Can you answer now please?

Comment: Where is the code snippet containing the import in your question? I can't see it.

Comment: @jabaa it is in the beginning. This is the only import I have. I am using require function to access .json file. I am not importing anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`main.js` is at the root of your repository. The import

```
const data = require('../JS/countries.json');
```

depends on the name of the folder containing your repository. Usually the name of the folder and the name of your repository are similar. That means that most users clone your repository into a folder `technical-question` and the import fails.

You can remove this dependency with

```
const data = require('./countries.json');
```

Now, the name of the parent folder isn't used in the import.

Answer (score -2):

try `npm install` in your terminal (npm is a package manager). This will install all the modules needed for your project with the help of package.json file which is probably already present in your project. In package.json you can find all the dependancies for your project and npm is going to install all of them in a new folder named node_modules. Hope this makes sense.